# Non- intuitive connected space.

Tags: general-topology, intuition

There exist knowing examples of connected spaces such that its picture is a counter intuitive  for us?. I mean a topology on a set who makes see the space as connected (no connected) but it is no connected (connected)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like "$[0,1]$ is disconnected in the discrete topology"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But an interesting example. :P

Comment: the [pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) is connected but every path component is a singleton. See this [MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57345/examples-of-g-delta-sets/185810#185810) for more references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mirko Swirko, you may want to look at indecomposable continua. A continuum is a compact connected Hausdorff space.  A continuum is indecomposable if it is not the union of two proper subcontinua.

The following theorem says that we can "almost" disconnect an indecomposable continuum.  Specifically, we can write $X$ as the union of two closed sets whose intersection is contained in an given open set.

**Theorem.**  If $X$ is an indecomposable continuum then for each open set $U$ there exists two nonempty closed sets $A$ and $B$ with $X=A\cup B$ and $A\cap B\subseteq U$.

**Another theorem.** If $X$ is a *metric* indecomposable continuum then we can partition $X$ into $2^\omega $ many dense subsets such that any proper closed subset of $X$ intersecting two of these partition sets is not connected!

The simplest example of a metric indecomposable continuum is the Knaster "buckethandle" continuum (google it).